# How to store a vector of LPD3DXSPRITE objects?

Tags: c++, vector, directx

Let's say I want to store a vector of LPD3DXSPRITE objects.  The line to declare this code would be `std::vector<LPD3DXSPRITE> sprites;`  I should be able to create my sprite with:

```
LPD3DXSPRITE sprite = NULL;
D3DXCreateSprite(myRenderingDevice, &sprite);
```

Finally, I should be able to add this to the vector like so:

```
sprites.push_back(sprite);
```

At least with my understanding, that should be plausible.  However, this compiles but gives runtime errors.  Why is this?  Am I going about it wrong?  How might I fix it?

**edit:**

This may be helpful as well.  The call stack yields for this function that `vector<ID3DXSprite *, std::allocator<ID3DXSprite *>>::push_back(ID3DXSprite * const &_Val=0x0036fd38` is what is called.  This is not the vector that it was passed.
However, LPD3DXSPRITE is just a typedef for ID3DXSprite *.  Could this bring anything to light?

Comment: What are the run-time errors?

Comment: Memory access violation.  It breaks at the size() function of the vector class.

Comment: are you checking the result of the D3DXCreateSprite call?

Comment: It's likely in your manipulation of the vector, then. Your code looks good to me, and I know I've done the same. What code uses the vector?

Comment: @GMan, none yet.  All code that was to use it is commented out.  All I'm doing is pushing this sprite into the vector.  It's really boggling my mind.

Comment: Pretty wild. If you don't mind, I have the time just to check our your whole project if you sent it somewhere, my email if you want.

Comment: Sure.  Not sure where I'd find access to your address.

Comment: You don't have to use the vector to corrupt it. You may be doing something else, and have a buffer overrun that "spills over" to the vector and corrupts it.

Comment: That's what I'm guessing too, something around vector is failing. I've added my email address to my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through your code, I found the problem. Something to look at when you get any breaks in your application is the "Autos" tab or the Locals tab. Here you'll notice something about the `this` pointer: it's null!

That means the instance that `AddSprite` is being called on doesn't exist. This is your `SpriteManager`, which I see is a singleton. In your main, you don't create an instance of it.

I had to do a couple things to get it working. I included `"LudoRenderer/SpriteManager.h"` in `Main.cpp`, and added the `CreateInstance` call:

```
SpriteManager::CreateInstance();
```

The only problem with this was that you had declared your constructor/destructor private, like other singletons, but never defined them, so I did that as well:

```
SpriteManager::SpriteManager(){}
SpriteManager::~SpriteManager(){}
```

After those changes, it "worked". That's in quotes because your problem is solved, but there is another error later in the code `m_GameManager->SetWagon(m_Wagon);`.

Here, `m_GameManager` is not initialized. I uncommented `m_GameManager = GameManager::GetInstance();` on line 43 in `LudoEngine.cpp`, which put us in the same problem as before, no `CreateInstance` is ever called. I added the necessary header in main, called the create method. This fixed the problem, and your engine ran (cool demo, too!)

There was a crash on exit, in `ErrorLogger::LogError`, because `ErrorLogger` was null. It was being called in `LudoMemory`'s destructor, but I'll leave this one for you. :)

Now, two tips I tihnk that would help. The first is about the issue we're solving. Normally, singletons will create themselves if they aren't already. I'd change your singleton `GetInstance` to something like this:

```
static T *GetInstance ( )
{
    if (!m_Singleton) // or == NULL or whatever you prefer
    {
        CreateInstance();
    }

    return m_Singleton; // not sure what the cast was for
}
```

This will force creation of the singleton if it hasn't been already. Now, if you'd like users to call `CreateInstance` before trying to `GetInstance`, you could add some sort of warning:

```
static T *GetInstance ( )
{
    if (!m_Singleton) // or == NULL or whatever you prefer
    {
        CreateInstance();
        std::cerr << "Warning, late creation of singleton!" << std::endl;

        // or perhaps:
        ErrorLogger::GetInstance()->
                        LogError(L"Warning, late creation of singleton!");
    }

    return m_Singleton;
}
```

Since that leaves out the important information "which singleton?", you could always try to add typeinfo to it:

```
#include <typeinfo>

// ...

std::cerr << "Warning, late creation of singleton: "
          << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
```

To try to get some type names in there.

And lastly, it's okay to `delete 0`, your checked delete macro is not needed.

To clarify, you have `LUDO_SAFE_DELETE`, which checks if it's not null before it calls delete. In C++, deleting null has no effect, so your check isn't needed. All instances of your safe delete could be replaced with just your LUDO_DELETE.

Comment: Amazing amount of detail.  Huge thanks for this.  Really helpful tips, as well.  With respect to your edit, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by it being okay to delete 0.

Comment: "ok to delete 0" means you can call `delete` on a NULL pointer and nohting bad should happen (http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.194233.15)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me. 
But you are storing a pointer to ID3DXSprite in the vector. How is this de-allocated? 
Is it possible the sprite has been de-allocated so the vector ends up holding an invalid pointer and then attempts to reference the pointer?